# WCF Config Differences. Getting Errors

Tags: c#, wcf

This is bothering me for two days now. I have created a WCF service and I have tested it locally and everything is fine. I purchased a hosting site and I have uploaded my WCF to the hosting site.

When I create a Windows Form application. I can add a service reference, which gives me the following information in the config file:

```
<system.serviceModel>
    <client>
        <endpoint address="http://www.verifythisaddress.com/AddressVerification/AddressVerificationService.svc/bh"
            binding="basicHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="bh" contract="AddressVerification.IAddressVerificationService"
            name="bh" />
        <endpoint address="http://www.verifythisaddress.com/AddressVerification/AddressVerificationService.svc/ws"
            binding="wsHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="ws" contract="AddressVerification.IAddressVerificationService"
            name="ws">
            <identity>
                <servicePrincipalName value="host/win5041.smarterasp.net" />
            </identity>
        </endpoint>
    </client>
    <bindings>
        <basicHttpBinding>
            <binding name="BasicHttpBinding_IECardBalanceService" />
            <binding name="bh" />
        </basicHttpBinding>
        <wsHttpBinding>
            <binding name="ws" />
        </wsHttpBinding>
    </bindings>
</system.serviceModel>
```

When I run this application it all works fine.

Now when I take my service and I put it in another class. The root config file of the application should have the same bindings correct? So I copy the binding out and paste them into the root web.config file and I get error messages like, "access is denied" or "it's http not https" and so forth. To note, I do not have ssl certificate on my machine.

So when I call this WCF config file:

```
**<?xml version="1.0"?>
<configuration>
  <connectionStrings>
    <add name="DBCS"  connectionString="cs"    providerName="System.Data.SqlClient"/>
  </connectionStrings>
  <appSettings>
    <add key="aspnet:UseTaskFriendlySynchronizationContext" value="true" />
  </appSettings>
  <system.web>
<compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.5" />
<httpRuntime targetFramework="4.5"/>
  </system.web>
  <system.serviceModel>
    <bindings>
      <basicHttpBinding>
        <binding name="BasicHttpBinding_IService">
          <security mode="Transport" />
        </binding>
        <binding name="soapEndpointGlobalAddressCheck">
          <security mode="Transport" />
        </binding>
        <binding name="soapSSLEndpointGlobalAddressCheck">
          <security mode="Transport" />
        </binding>
      </basicHttpBinding>
    </bindings>
    <client>
     <endpoint address="https://addresscheck.melissadata.net/v2/SOAP/Service.svc"
        binding="basicHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="BasicHttpBinding_IService"
        contract="MelissaDataService.IService" name="BasicHttpBinding_IService" />
      <endpoint address="http://address.melissadata.net/v3/SOAP/GlobalAddress"
         binding="basicHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="soapSSLEndpointGlobalAddressCheck"
        contract="globalcheck.AddressCheckSoap" name="soapEndpointGlobalAddressCheck" />
      <endpoint address="https://address.melissadata.net/v3/SOAP/GlobalAddress"
         binding="basicHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="soapSSLEndpointGlobalAddressCheck"
         contract="globalcheck.AddressCheckSoap" name="soapSSLEndpointGlobalAddressCheck" />
    </client>
    <behaviors>
      <serviceBehaviors>
        <behavior>
           <!-- To avoid disclosing metadata information, set the values below to false before deployment -->
          <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true" httpsGetEnabled="true"/>
          <!-- To receive exception details in faults for debugging purposes, set the value below to true.  Set to false before deployment to avoid disclosing exception information -->
           <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="false"/>
        </behavior>
       </serviceBehaviors>
     </behaviors>
    <protocolMapping>
       <add binding="basicHttpBinding" scheme="http"></add>
       <add binding="basicHttpsBinding" scheme="https" />
    </protocolMapping>
    <serviceHostingEnvironment aspNetCompatibilityEnabled="true" multipleSiteBindingsEnabled="true" />
    <services>
      <service name="AddressVerificationWCF.AddressVerficationService">
        <endpoint address="bh" name="bh" binding="basicHttpBinding" contract="AddressVerificationWCF.IAddressVerificationService"></endpoint>
        <endpoint address="ws" name="ws" binding="wsHttpBinding" contract="AddressVerificationWCF.IAddressVerificationService"></endpoint>
       </service>
    </services>
  </system.serviceModel>
  <system.webServer>
    <modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true"/>
    <!--
        To browse web app root directory during debugging, set the value below to true.
        Set to false before deployment to avoid disclosing web app folder information.
      -->
    <directoryBrowse enabled="true"/>
  </system.webServer>
</configuration>**
```

Now if I take the config from the top section and I put it in the base config file of the other application that I am running and all the code that calls the service is the same as the first application that works. I get and access is denied error.

I am calling the webservice like this:

```
AddressService.IAddressVerificationService client = new AddressService.AddressVerificationServiceClient("bh");
```

So I am trying to figure out, why it works for one, doesn't work for the other. Any pointers would be much appreciated.

I would ultimately like to do this:

```
        EndpointAddress endpointAddress = new EndpointAddress("http://www.verifythisaddress.com/AddressVerification/AddressVerificationService.svc/bh");
        BasicHttpBinding serviceBinding = new BasicHttpBinding(BasicHttpSecurityMode.None);
        serviceBinding.Security.Transport.ClientCredentialType = HttpClientCredentialType.Windows;
        serviceBinding.ReceiveTimeout = new TimeSpan(0, 0, 120);

        AddressService.IAddressVerificationService client = new AddressService.AddressVerificationServiceClient(serviceBinding, endpointAddress);
```

Comment: Can you update the question with some of the exact error messages you're getting?

Comment: The exact error message was "Access is denied"

Comment: Access is denied? Have you try to give full permission?

Answer (score 0):

IN your bindings:

```
<bindings>
  <basicHttpBinding>
    <binding name="BasicHttpBinding_IService">
      <security mode="None" />
    </binding>
    <binding name="soapEndpointGlobalAddressCheck">
      <security mode="None" />
    </binding>
    <binding name="soapSSLEndpointGlobalAddressCheck">
      <security mode="None" />
    </binding>
  </basicHttpBinding>
</bindings>
```

Set security mode to none.  You also have some of the endPoints as

> Https://

You should probably get rid of those and just use http:// since you do not have a certificate.

The following is all I needed to invoke your service after generating the clients:

```
    <system.serviceModel>
    <bindings>
        <basicHttpBinding>
            <binding name="soapEndpointGlobalAddressCheck" />
            <binding name="soapSSLEndpointGlobalAddressCheck">
                <security mode="None" />
            </binding>
            <binding name="BasicHttpBinding_IService">
                <security mode="Transport" />
            </binding>
        </basicHttpBinding>
    </bindings>
    <client>
        <endpoint address="http://address.melissadata.net/v3/SOAP/GlobalAddress"
            binding="basicHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="soapEndpointGlobalAddressCheck"
            contract="AddressTest.AddressCheckSoap" name="soapEndpointGlobalAddressCheck" />
        <endpoint address="https://addresscheck.melissadata.net/v2/SOAP/Service.svc"
            binding="basicHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="BasicHttpBinding_IService"
            contract="AddressVersionTwo.IService" name="BasicHttpBinding_IService" />
    </client>
</system.serviceModel>
```

Comment: Thanks, this still gives the same error of Access is Denied.

Comment: This is the service I want to invoke though:<services>
      <service name="AddressVerificationWCF.AddressVerficationService">
        <endpoint address="bh" name="bh" binding="basicHttpBinding" contract="AddressVerificationWCF.IAddressVerificationService"></endpoint>
        <endpoint address="ws" name="ws" binding="wsHttpBinding" contract="AddressVerificationWCF.IAddressVerificationService"></endpoint>
       </service>
    </services>

Comment: so, you want your clients to create a proxy for the verifythisaddress.com service(your service) and your service will invoke the address.melissadata service?

Comment: correct. however, I noticed in a log trace that my barracuda server may be blocking the request. I am going to check that soon.

Comment: This is what I find odd. If I take this code and run it in windows form it works fine. And then if I take the EXACT same code and run it in another application it doesn't work and throws access is denied. I just don't get it.

Comment: EndpointAddress endpointAddress = new EndpointAddress("http://www.verifythisaddress.com/AddressVerification/AddressVerificationService.svc/bh");
                BasicHttpBinding serviceBinding = new BasicHttpBinding(BasicHttpSecurityMode.None);
                serviceBinding.Security.Transport.ClientCredentialType = HttpClientCredentialType.Windows;
                serviceBinding.ReceiveTimeout = new TimeSpan(0, 0, 120);

                AddressService.IAddressVerificationService client = new AddressService.AddressVerificationServiceClient(serviceBinding, endpointAddress);

Answer (score 0):

The first `serviceModel` listing (the one which works) is not completely integrated into the last listing - only the bindings seem to have been copied. So the `bindings` and `endpoints` should match exactly if I've understood the question correctly. If the location of the service has changed, then only the `address` url should be different.

Also, the final listing is missing the identity section, which could be the cause of the "Access Denied" message

```
 <identity>
     <servicePrincipalName value="host/win5041.smarterasp.net" />
 </identity>
```

Comment: Thanks, this still gives the same error of Access is Denied.

Comment: Okay I see what your saying. So let me clarify a little more. I have a WCF service. This service is calling out to another WCF service somewhere else. That is why you see the bindings and endpoints in the second model, but not in the first.  The first model (the one that works) creates a service reference to MY WCF that I want it to talk to. So shouldn't that just be the bindings that I am concerned with?